# Powershell Function - how to deal with multiple return values?

Tags: powershell, function, return

I have a Powershell function with multiple return values. But one value should only be returned when it is not **empty**.

```
if ($value4 -ne '')
{
    return + $value4
}

return $value1, $value2, $value3
```

That does not work. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show us what object type `$value4` is? (a string, an array, a complex object or..) and what you expect returned? an array holding these values?

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, `return` happens once: it terminates the function and returns the specified object(s) into the pipeline to the caller.

In your case this is indeed multiple objects. Your example suggests you're reaching for a pattern to decide to add another object to the return, as if you're accumulating the list along the way, and you can do that.

```
$return = @($value1, $value2, $value3)

if ($null -ne $value4)
{
    $return += $value4
}

return $return
```

The @() en-listing operator is, in this example, syntactic sugar to state that we're creating a 3 element list. It is not strictly needed here because the comma operator does create a list even if it was omitted.

Where @() would be necessary is if we needed to create a single element list to append to.

```
$return = 1
$return += 2

$return ====> 3
```

SO

```
$return = @(1)
$return += 2

$return ====> @(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `return` once. The use of `if/else` is to determine which of two (or more) outcomes should be derived from a test.

The correct way to write your `return` statement in conjunction with the `if/else` is as follows:

```
if ($null -ne $value4)
{
    return $value1, $value2, $value3, $value4
}
else
{
    return $value1, $value2, $value3
}
```

There should be no code following that closing `Else` statement.

PS - I have opted to use `$null` value check instead of `String.Empty` like you have. Using `''` is the C# equivalent of `String.Empty`.

So you could write it like this:

```
if ($value4 -ne String.Empty)
{
    return $value1, $value2, $value3, $value4
}
else
{
    return $value1, $value2, $value3
}
```